# Android: Is it possible to cut/paste android SDK and use it?

Tags: android, installation

I am using eclipse as IDE for android programming. I have update android SDK to API 9. these are installed on my laptop.

Now, I want to transfer all of these to my PC. On my PC, I didn't have eclipse and SDK.

My question is, may I copy folders of eclipse and SDK from laptop and paste it on my PC? can I use it and create new project after this?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, the time you spend writing this question and waiting for an answer could have been used for the file transfer. It should be possible to do it as you say.

Comment: ya i have done with the same kind of transfer, so i was having success at that time, so its possible

Comment: Did u get working ? copy and paste of sdk file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and see is the best answer to this.

My suggestions is to launch eclipse on your desktop and get ADT.

Otherwise I think you have to be careful where your Android SDK is. if you put in Eclipse then it should work.

(In my case I needed the SDK and NDK to be at the root of C:)

bottom line there is not better way than a clean installation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just copy the whole project (your app) folders over to your PC. In Eclipse, use the File/Import… command, then select General/Existing Projects into Workspace to add the copied project/s to your Eclipse workspace.

As for the Android SDK folder, I wouldn't transfer that one over, and just run the SDK installer for Windows again on the second PC to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Very much. Just copy and paste. This should work in most cases. (Except if you try to transfer a 64bit eclipse version to a 32bit machine. If this happens just download the eclipse 32 bit version and point your workspace and android SDK to the copied one).

Copy paste has and advantage if you are planning to generate debug key (need this if you are using Location Information using Google API). If you copy paste, you dont have to keep generating a new key per machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy all the things as far as you keep respecting the path changes. Keep track of them and change paths in Eclipse. You must have Java although.