# Android Api Installation-For Latest Version

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have been working in eclipse and android sdk for more than a year. i use to install new api when it released by the google by android sdk manager.

Now my question is can I download it once and can I use it in some other system?

Comment: you can use android sdk by copy and paste android-sdk folder to other system (same os) and set path in eclipse preference

Comment: Before that, have you tried first?

Answer (score 0):

You can install using android SDK Manager. Open it and install which ever SDK you need. 
If u want to use this in another computer, copy total eclipse and paste in another system.
Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.... create complete environment of eclipse on another system as previous system, where you download android-sdk and then use downloaded android-sdk...
may it's also help you...
[Android: Is it possible to cut/paste android SDK and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446695/android-is-it-possible-to-cut-paste-android-sdk-and-use-it)

Comment: first thanks @sham- sdk is not an issue in my case.... see i have all the things related to 4.0 version . so i need to install the 4.4 version tools. for this only am asking.

Comment: Currently You are using 4.0 version. Try to run 4.4 version apps on android 4.0?